# android display data by dragging your finger

Tags: android

I have to show a graph, when you drag your finger across it, the view should display data.

I have seen that this is possible when you click with "onclicklistener" but is it also possible in this way?

thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for something like the `GestureListener` with use of `ACTION_MOVE` `MotionEvents`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

Answer (score 0):

use

```
     @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event ) {
    float x = event.getX( );
        float y = event.getY( );
     if ( event.getAction( ) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
    //Do something interesting
    }else if ( event.getAction( ) == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ) {
    //Do something exciting
    }else if ( event.getAction( ) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
//Do something boring
}
```